# Fixing this ClassCastException

Tags: java, polymorphism, classcastexception

So I have this method that is supposed to return a BinaryHeap:

```
public static BinaryHeap legendToHeap(String legend) {
    String[] legendArray = legend.split(" ");
    HuffmanNode[] huffArray = new HuffmanNode[legendArray.length/2];
    for (int i = 0; i < legendArray.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        String letterA = " ";
        double freqA = 0.0;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            letterA = legendArray[i];
        } else {
            String str = legendArray[i].replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
            freqA = Double.parseDouble(str);
        }
        if (!letterA.isEmpty() && freqA != 0.0) {
            HuffmanNode newNode = new HuffmanNode(letterA, freqA);
            huffArray[count] = newNode;
            count++;
        }
    }
    BinaryHeap newBinaryHeap = new BinaryHeap((Comparable[]) huffArray);
    //newBinaryHeap.printHeap();
    return newBinaryHeap;   
}
```

A problem arises in the constructor BinaryHeap(...) - this is a part of the code given from my assignment for the BinaryHeapClass.

```
public class BinaryHeap<E extends Comparable>
{
 /**
  * Construct the binary heap.
  */
 public BinaryHeap( )
 {
     this( DEFAULT_CAPACITY );
 }
 public int getSize() {
     return currentSize;
 }
 /**
  * Construct the binary heap given an array of items.
   */
   public BinaryHeap( E [ ] items )
   {
     currentSize = items.length;
     array = (E[]) new Comparable[ ( currentSize + 2 ) * 11 / 10 ];

     int i = 1;
     for( E item : items )
         array[ i++ ] = item;
     buildHeap( );
    }
```

I get a ClassCastException I don't quite understand. The constructor says that for public BinaryHeap(E [ ] items) I can construct a BinaryHeap given an array of items. So, E [ ] in this case is the class object HuffmanNodes. I got an error that BinaryHeap(HuffmanNode[]) is undefined (which I don't quite understand) so I tried to cast it to Comparables (the platform suggested it) I get the ClassCastException saying I can't cast a HuffmanNode to Comparables. I think I have a pretty poor concept of polymorphism at this point and I'm trying understand how to resolve this error. Any advice or suggestions would be of great help!

Comment: What happens if you don't cast your huffArray to Comparable, near the end of the first code block?

Comment: @marcellorvalle I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor BinaryHeap(HuffmanNode[]) is undefined

Comment: What about new BinaryHeap<HuffmanNode>(huffArray) ?

Comment: @marcellorvalle Bound mismatch: The type HuffmanNode is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable> of the type BinaryHeap<E>
:(

Comment: Ok... it seems that you need to implement comparable on your HuffmannNode class.